# Session timeout - HTTP Status code -1 in Spring boot + Angular application

Tags: angularjs, spring, http

My application is using spring boot & angular. I am handling session timeout in **Angular Interceptor**'s "ResponseError" function. At server side , I added a HTTPSessionListener.

**I tested this timeout like below:** .

1). I set the server session timeout as 120 seconds,

2).logged in to the application ,

3).kept open Internet explorer developer console,

4).waited for 120 seconds to get over,

5).after that , clicked a link which triggers a request to server,

6)now debugging in Internet explorer developer console to see which interceptor function is called ,

Below is the result...

- Angular Interceptor's Response Error Method is called
- HTTP Status code is -1 ( YES minus 1, I am clueless)
- HTTP status text is empty string.

7)now , again clicking an link, and getting the same result as above.

Now my question is , **Why am getting HTTP response code -1 and what is the meaning of this?**

Comment: 0 is for server not answering, -1 is probably for somthing like that. Not an HTTP Code, more likely a system code.

Answer (score 0):

Having a simular issue when using $http.post in angular. -1 is a SIS error code instead of a http error code.

Take a look here:
http://community.hpe.com/t5/Application-Perf-Mgmt-BAC-BSM/Possible-negative-status-codes-in-SiteScope/td-p/6560226